# Adding actionbutton in shiny dashboardheader

Tags: r, shiny

Below is my ui code

```
> dashboardHeader(title = uiOutput("flex_logo"),
>                   tags$li(class = "dropdown",
>                           tags$a("Help",target="_blank",href="Flex-Forecasting_Usage_Guidelines.pdf",
>                            style="font-weight: bold;color:white;")),
>                   tags$li(class = "dropdown",tags$a(href="mailto:flex-forecasting_support@eclerx.com?subject=
> flex-forecasting","Contact us",style="font-weight:
> bold;color:white;")),
>                   tags$li(class = "dropdown",tags$a("Change password",actionLink("ChangePassword","Change
> Password"),style="font-weight: bold;color:white;")),
>                   tags$li(class ="dropdown",dropdownMenu(type = "notifications",
>                           notificationItem(text = "No new notification",status = "success")
>                          # notificationItem(text = "Nnet & Nnetx takes time to converge",status = "success")
>                           
>                   )))
> 
>
```

I want the Change Password button in same format and style as help and contact us,but when i add actionbutton OR actionlink,not able to get the same format and alignment respectively.

Alternatively if i add a tagname(Change password it has the same format,but i want to link it with observe function further

Comment: May be you could provide a minimal and fully reproductible code ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are giving the `style` parameter to `tag$a`, so you are stylizing the hyperlink and not the button. You should have used it into `actionLink` i.e. : `actionLink("ChangePassword", "Change Password", style = "font-weight: bold;color:white;")`

Also you don't have to wrap your `actionButton` in `tag$a` and since you use the same `style` for several items then you can create a custom css class with the desire style and it will applies to every tags having the same class

```
shinyApp(
  ui = dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
      tags$li(class = "dropdown", tags$a(href = "", class = "my_class", "Help", target="_blank")), 
      tags$li(class = "dropdown", tags$a(href = "", class = "my_class", "Contact us")),
      tags$li(class = "dropdown", actionLink("ChangePassword", "Change Password", class = "my_class"))),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                      .my_class {
                      font-weight: bold;
                      color:white;
                      }"))
    )),
    title = "Dashboard example"
  ),
  server = function(input, output) { }
)
```